# Google Tag Manager + IE8 generating 404s

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, http-status-code-404, google-tag-manager, silent

Because I use a tool sending an email everytime a 404 page is thrown, I noticed I've got lots of weird ones.

They're all on a **"truncated" url**, the last part's missing. For example for `mywebsite.com/lp/landing`, I get a 404 error on `mywebsite.com/lp` (this route doesn't exist).

I also noticed those 404s are only thrown by **IE8** (seeing the user agents).

When you go on this page with IE8 you don't see any error, though the server still throw this 404.

After few tests, I found out this is from some JS (disabling JS in IE8 didn't throw any 404). So I had to remove all my JS files, and finally found that the problem is from the **Google Tag Manager script** !

```
<noscript><iframe src='//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-Q36B'
            height='0' width='0' style='display:none;visibility:hidden'></iframe></noscript>
            <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-Q36B');</script>
```

I don't find anything about this issue, any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Did the below answer help solve your issue? Mark it as correct if so.

Comment: I actually have no idea, but my GTM wasn't empty. I had to "clean" all the partners scripts or whatever, keeping only the useful ones, and at the end I had no problem anymore..

Comment: Oh ok. You can provide an answer of what you changed and then mark it as the correct one. Won't provide any points, but at least future visitors will be able to see it. Up to you though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can't be more specific about the resolution, I actually just cleaned GTM removing all the unused scripts and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the GTM script will 404 until you add a tag. I couldn't find this documented anywhere either.